# How to call function from controller into javascript tag blade.php LARAVEL

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to call save function from my controller into javascript tag in my blade.php but javascript cannot recognize my function.My idea is make that javascript to do my function every 1 minute.

What the thing I missed out? Is it possible to do that?

Here my function in controller

```
public function savelivemarket(){

        $token = $this->tomeiToken();
        $client = new Client();
        $connect2= 'https://uat.fxinside.net';


        $params = [
            'headers' => ['SSO_TOKEN' => $token],

        ];

        $online_data = null;
        $online_data2 = null;
        $online_data3 = null;
        $online_data4 = null;

        try{

            $online_response = $client->request('GET', $connect2.'/v2/rates/spot/FULL/TXGApp?symbol=XAU500GMM/MYR',$params);

            $online_statusCode = $online_response->getStatusCode();
            $online_body = $online_response->getBody()->getContents();

            $online_data = json_decode($online_body);

//            dd($online_data);

        } catch (ClientException $e) {
//            dd( Psr7\Message::toString($e->getRequest()),Psr7\Message::toString($e->getResponse()),$e->getMessage(),$token);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
//            dd($e->getMessage());
        }

        try{

            $online_response2 = $client->request('GET', $connect2.'/v2/rates/spot/FULL/TXGApp?symbol=GS900GMM/MYR',$params);

            $online_statusCode = $online_response->getStatusCode();
            $online_body2 = $online_response2->getBody()->getContents();

            $online_data2 = json_decode($online_body2);

//            dd($online_data);

        } catch (ClientException $e) {
//            dd( Psr7\Message::toString($e->getRequest()),Psr7\Message::toString($e->getResponse()),$e->getMessage(),$token);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
//            dd($e->getMessage());
        }

        try{

            $online_response3 = $client->request('GET', $connect2.'/v2/rates/spot/FULL/TXGApp?symbol=XAG1GMS/SGD',$params);

            $online_statusCode = $online_response->getStatusCode();
            $online_body3 = $online_response3->getBody()->getContents();

            $online_data3 = json_decode($online_body3);

//            dd($online_data);

        } catch (ClientException $e) {
//            dd( Psr7\Message::toString($e->getRequest()),Psr7\Message::toString($e->getResponse()),$e->getMessage(),$token);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
//            dd($e->getMessage());
        }

        try{

            $online_response4 = $client->request('GET', $connect2.'/v2/rates/spot/FULL/TXGApp?symbol=XAGKGM/MYR',$params);

            $online_statusCode = $online_response->getStatusCode();
            $online_body4 = $online_response4->getBody()->getContents();

            $online_data4 = json_decode($online_body4);

//            dd($online_data);

        } catch (ClientException $e) {
//            dd( Psr7\Message::toString($e->getRequest()),Psr7\Message::toString($e->getResponse()),$e->getMessage(),$token);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
//            dd($e->getMessage());
        }

        if(isset($online_data)){
            try{
                DB::beginTransaction();
//                dd('a');
                $ratehistory = new RateHistory();
                $ratehistory->symbol = '$online_data[0]->symbol[0]';
                $ratehistory->bid_price = '$online_data[0]->bid[0]';
                $ratehistory->offer_price = '$online_data[0]->offer[0]';

                $ratehistory->save();

//            dd($payout);

                DB::commit();

            }catch (\Exception $e){
                DB::rollback();
//            dd($e->getMessage());
                return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors('Failed To Add Payout');
//                return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

then here my javascript function in blade.php

```
    <script>
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                      setInterval(function(){
                          $.ajax({
                              url: "savelivemarket()",
                              success: function( response ) {
                                  // update div
                              }
                          });
                      },6000);
                  });
    </script>
```

route web.php

[image]

Comment: `savelivemarket()` is a PHP function, and you can't call it as a URL, let alone as a URL in JavaScript... In Laravel, you define a Route that uses that function, then in JavaScript, you can do a `$.ajax()` call to that Route, using it's associated URL. You're gonna have to read all of the documentation on how Routing works: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#basic-routing and see if you can figure it out. Or, consider some tutorials on how Laravel Routing works with AJAX. This answer is missing _a lot_, and likely cannot be answered directly.

Comment: I already have the route.

Comment: My blade.php is a tab that available for every route or page. So I want my function in controller can be run for every 1 minute in every page. Not only when I click to the page only.